# Easy hide/hover effect with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, show-hide

It's an easy question and I've done it several times before, but for some reason, it's not working this time. I have an image and when a user hovers it, a description should show.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="description custom">
   <a class="description_help_text" href="">
     <img src="../../misc/help.png">
     <span>Bla bla bla.</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.description a.description_help_text span {
    display: none;
}

div.description a.description_help_text a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

But for some reason, it's not working. I'm guessing some kind of stupid syntax I'm overlooking right now.

And a second question, is it possible to use a `a`-tag without linking it? So a user can click on it as much as he wants, but with no actions from the browser?

Comment: how is it not working? for `a` tag not linking anywhere use `<a href="javascript:void(0);" ></a>`

Comment: just use the anchor without href ... in this case you have to force  handcourser with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS should work fine, so my guess is that you have a parent class somewhere which is affecting it. Try looking through the ascendent styles in Firebug.

Re. your second question, you can supply no `href` value to an anchor element, but this may still cause the page to jump when the link is clicked, and IIRC it is not valid HTML. An alternative is to link to `javascript:void(0);`, although this is rather ugly IMO.

The only way to fully prevent any link behaviour is to create a link handler for the element in javascript and place `event.preventDefault();` within it.

Comment: You were right. There was some other parent class blocking the flow of my css. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the latter CSS block should be

```
div.description a.description_help_text:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

For the links without action I recommend using

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: yes that's it :) because there is no anchor child in the anchor

Comment: using `<a href="#">link</a>` is not what he's looking for see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qVK6f/

to answer your second question at least, try:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">click</a>
```